# Ionic 4 Open Native Settings Plugin not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am using “open-native-settings” on my ionic 4 project. Based on the documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/open-native-settings#usage
My implementation as bellow.

myclass.module.ts:

```
import { OpenNativeSettings } from '@ionic-native/open-native-settings/ngx';


providers:[
    OpenNativeSettings
  ],
```

myclass.ts file:

```
import { OpenNativeSettings } from '@ionic-native/open-native-settings/ngx';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(
    private openNativeSettings: OpenNativeSettings,
    private _platform: Platform) {}
```

inside a method

```
this._platform.ready().then(() => {
          // open settings
          this.openNativeSettings.open("about").then(val => {
            console.log('success')
          });

        });
```

I don't get any compilation errors. But when I call the method, app shows below runtime error.

[image]

any suggestions?? Thanks

Comment: Your should add this in your `app.module.ts` as well.

Comment: @NajamusSaqib Thanks for the suggestion. But I managed to resolve the issue by downgrading plugin version as bellow answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue in my case. Since I am using ionic v4.x, I downgraded open-native-settings plugin version to 4.x

`npm install @ionic-native/open-native-settings@4`

Then import without /ngx. All other codes as same as above

```
import { OpenNativeSettings } from '@ionic-native/open-native-settings';
```